# Spring bean creation error out of nowhere

Tags: java, spring

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at com.mdpartner.dashboard.DashboardApplication.main(DashboardApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.core.BridgeMethodResolver.findBridgedMethod(BridgeMethodResolver.java:60) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.<init>(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:70) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.buildGenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:348) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:177) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:63) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyHandler(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:725) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.isWritableProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:557) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
... 20 common frames omitted
```

This is the complete error message I receive. It doesn't have anything to do with the code I wrote. Maybe there is something wrong with the dependencies but I couldn't figure out what. What may be the cause behind this?

Comment: can you post your maven dependencies pom.xml ? it looks like you're mixing incompatible version of spring and spring boot

Comment: @Jayesh yeah that was the case. The jdbi bom was forcing two Spring dependencies to a lower version than the one spring boot works with. I removed the bom and declared the jdbi version in the dependency. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing incompatible spring and spring boot versions. Please check comparability in maven dependency.